# When installing Artery on Ubuntu, building INET throws an unusual Error

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I am currently setting up a new PC with Omnet++, Veins and Artery for simulating ITS-G5 protocol. After calling `make inet` in the root directory of Artery I get the following Error Message:

```
$ make inet
cd extern/inet; python inet_featuretool disable packetdrill SCTP SCTP_examples
Disabling feature(s):  packetdrill, SCTP_examples, SCTP
opp_featuretool: .oppfeaturestate file updated.
opp_featuretool: .nedexclusions file updated.
make -C extern/inet makefiles
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/wiconlab/Car2x/artery-master/extern/inet'
Creating Makefile in /home/wiconlab/Car2x/artery-master/extern/inet/src...
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/wiconlab/Car2x/artery-master/extern/inet'
make -C extern/inet/src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/wiconlab/Car2x/artery-master/extern/inet/src'
*** COMPILING with:
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O3 -march=native -mtune=native -DNDEBUG=1 -MMD -MP -MF .d  -fPIC  -fno-stack-protector -DHAVE_SWAPCONTEXT -DWITH_MPI -DXMLPARSER=libxml -DPREFER_QTENV -DWITH_QTENV -DWITH_TKENV -DWITH_PARSIM -DWITH_NETBUILDER -DWITH_OSG -DWITH_OSGEARTH -Wno-overloaded-virtual -include inet/common/precompiled.h   -I. -I/home/wiconlab/Car2x/omnetpp-5.2/include
*** LINKING with:
g++ -shared -fPIC -o ../out/gcc-release/src/libINET.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--whole-archive  -Wl,--no-whole-archive -loppenvir -loppsim -ldl -lstdc++  -lOpenThreads -losg -losgText -losgDB -losgEarth -losgEarthUtil -Wl,-rpath,/home/wiconlab/Car2x/omnetpp-5.2/lib -Wl,-rpath,/lib -Wl,-rpath,.  -L/home/wiconlab/Car2x/omnetpp-5.2/lib
Building...
Creating precompiled header for gcc...
MSGC: inet/applications/base/ApplicationPacket.msg

...  *ABBREVIATED FOR CLARITY*

inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc: In member function ‘virtual void inet::RoutingTableRecorder::recordInterfaceChange(omnetpp::cModule*, const inet::InterfaceEntry*, omnetpp::simsignal_t)’:
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc:207:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘INT64_PRINTF_FORMAT’
 #define LL    INT64_PRINTF_FORMAT  // for eventnumber_t
           ^
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc:296:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘LL’
 fprintf(routingLogFile, "%s  %" LL "d  %s  %d  %s %s\n",
                                 ^
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc:303:13: warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]
         );
         ^
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc:303:13: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc: In member function ‘virtual void inet::RoutingTableRecorder::recordRouteChange(omnetpp::cModule*, const inet::IRoute*, omnetpp::simsignal_t)’:
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc:207:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘INT64_PRINTF_FORMAT’
 #define LL    INT64_PRINTF_FORMAT  // for eventnumber_t
           ^
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc:323:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘LL’
 fprintf(routingLogFile, "%s %" LL "d  %s  %d  %s  %s  %d  %s\n",
                                ^
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc:332:13: warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]
         );
         ^
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc:332:13: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
Makefile:1134: recipe for target '../out/gcc-release/src/inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.o' failed
make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-release/src/inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/wiconlab/Car2x/artery-master/extern/inet/src'
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'inet' failed
make: *** [inet] Error 2
```

I am using an up to date **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**, compiling with **cmake 3.9.6**, building Veins and Vanetza worked without issue. **Omnet++ Version is 5.2**. The code lines, the Error is referring to are:

```
203 namespace inet {
204
205 Define_Module(RoutingTableRecorder);
206
207 #define LL    INT64_PRINTF_FORMAT  // for eventnumber_t
```

However expecting a ")" before line 207 makes no sense to me.
Also, this Error did not appear when building Artery on a different System (Same OS) a few weeks earlier. Using an earlier revision of the source had no effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **OMNeT++ 5.2**.
This seems to be the problem because the API has changed slightly.

`INT64_PRINTF_FORMAT` isn't available anymore in **OMNeT++ 5.2**.

Changing back to **OMNeT++ Version 5.1** should resolve your error!

Answer (score -1):

fprintf(routingLogFile, "%s %" LL "d  %s  %d  %s  %s  %d  %s\n",
                                ^
inet/networklayer/ipv4/RoutingTableRecorder.cc:332:13: warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]
         );

This is just a simple syntax error. Go through the path Inet/src/inet/networlayer/ipv4/ and open the RoutingTableRecord.cc file and edit at "fprintf(routingLogFile, "%s %" LL "d  %s  %d  %s  %s  %d  %s\n", " line and remove LL including the double quotes that is around the LL. There are two of them with in this C code. So make sure they are both corrected like the following line: fprintf(routingLogFile, "%s %d  %s  %d  %s  %s  %d  %s\n", .

You might also need to comment out #define LL    INT64_PRINTF_FORMAT  // for eventnumber_t at line number around 270.

Then save and Clean only the inet project. Then Build also only the inet project.

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).